# How can I fill a certain value to input after each reset event?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

HTML Form `reset` event fires before the form actually go clear its form fields.

```
  <form id="wrapper-form"
    <input id="something-needs-to-be-filled-after-each-reset" />
  </form>
```

If I hook an event listener on the `reset` event, to fill a certain value, it would get washed out by the ensuing clear.

```
document.querySelector("form#wrapper-form").addEventListener("reset", evt => document.querySelector("input#something-needs-to-be-filled-after-each-reset").value="something_to_be_filled_on_each_reset";);
```

How can I make this listener execute after the form has actually been cleared?

Comment: You need some value after reset means you need some default value. You can set a value for the input initially. Say ```<input id="input1" value="default" />```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="something-needs-to-be-filled-after-each-reset" 
value="something_to_be_filled_on_each_reset" />
```

or you can having a function that firing bu click on reset button

Comment: This won't work, as whatever value you set, it will immediately washed away by the following reset.